# Best way to design a dashboard based on a SharePoint list with KPI

Tags: dashboard, kpi

I have a SharePoint list with 100+ KPI which has a target and actual goals with KPI title.

How do I show KPI indicators for these data?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an SharePoint online or on prem? Modern or classic UI? Can you give a short sample of your data? A few rows and a few columns. To get an idea.

Comment: I added the print shot of how KPIs are stored in a SharePoint list. We are on SharePoint 2013 on-prem with PowerPivot / Excel services enabled.

Comment: how do you want the KPI's to be displayed?